# SSIS merge join giving null results while adding more columns to one of the sources

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am trying to use the merge join in ssis; however, when i am putting in two columns on basis of which i am joining it is giving me correct results. But as soon as I add more columns in one of the sources, it gives me matches with nulls only.
[image]

Comment: Do you have an `order by` in both of your sources? Are the columns the same data type? Please post sample data

Comment: Hello @Nick.McDermaid : yes i have added order by in sql command  (oledb source)while I am fetching the data. Everything works perfectly if I just fetch the fields on which I am joining but as soon as i add more fields it kind of craps out..

Comment: You'll need to post screenshots of the Merge Join configuration for us to be able to help you further.

Comment: You'll have to provide more info. "Craps Out" is a useless description.